# Функция max с 3 аргументами С++

Tags: c++, c, математика

Итак, есть задача в которой попадается функция max с 3 аргументами, но у стандартной функции max может существовать всего 2 аргумента, и действительно при попытке ввести третий аргумент выбивает ошибку `C2064 результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 2 аргументов`

Источник: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Что можно было бы сделать в таком случае, и насколько мое решение верно?

Условие задачи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мое решение:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
double max3(double a1, const double b1, const double c1) 
{
    return a1 > b1 ? a1 > c1 ? a1 : c1 : b1 > c1 ? b1 : c1; // max3 = max(a + b * c, 1., 15.)
}
double maximum(double a, double b, double c, double max3)
{
    return (max(a, a + b) + max(a, b + c)) / (1 + max3);
}
int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    const double b1 = 1.;
    const double c1 = 15.;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    double a1 = a + b * c;
    cout << "Answer: " << maximum(a, b, c,max3(a1, b1, c1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимум от n переменных - это максимум от переменной и остальных n-1 переменных.

```
double max3(double a1, double b1, double c1)
{
    return max(max(a1,b1),c1)
}
```

Да, и `const` тут совсем ни к чему - при передаче по значению.

P.S. Пока тыкал в капчу и искал автобусы, светофоры и переходы, меня опередили.

Comment: Все равно спасибо)

Comment: Если еще один ответ и плюсик, получу сегодня 10000 баллов :)

Comment: @Mikhailo No problem. Поздравляю.

Comment: Я думаю что Игорь не сильно обидится, если я Вам отдам ответ (Но ему тоже огромная благодарность)

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, теперь ночь спать не буду, празднуя ))) О, интересно, пока любовался круглой цифрой, выяснил, что я скоро 5 лет как на сайте. Бывстро время летит, что и говорить.

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с `C++11`, `std::max` понимает `initializer_list` из любого количества аргументов, что позволяет избавиться от велосипедов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    double a = 33;
    double b = -2;
    const double c = 12;
    cout << max({a,b,c}) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Пример на IDEONE](https://ideone.com/18Xmeh)

Answer (score 2):

```
double max3(const double a1, const double b1, const double c1) 
{
    return max(max(a1, b1), c1);
}
```

Comment: Действительно, выглядит аккуратнее, но сравнив с моим результатом я понял что и мое решение +- работает, верно?